# Len function gives incorrect results

Tags: python, list, string-length

I am trying to find the len of my list but when I do it, it gives incorrect results. Not sure why or how to fix it. Any suggestions what might be wrong with my code? From the photo you can see from the highlighted row that it shows count is 2 but there are more than 2 elements

[Photo of code and df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMOrw.png)

[Items per row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6jh.png)

Items for first 5 rows:

```
1. ['Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'inspiratie,email,nieuwsbrief,E-mail - Nieuwsbrief', 'inspiratie,email,nieuwsbrief,E-mail - Nieuwsbrief']
```

2. ['(not set),email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', '(direct),(none),(not set),Direct']
3. ['Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional']
4. ['Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional']
5. ['Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', 'Unknown,email,transactional,Email - Transactional', '(not set),email,transactional,Email - Transactional']

Code:

```
def calc(path):
    return len(path)

df_journey['path_count']= df_journey.apply(lambda x: calc(x.path), axis=1)
```

Comment: Please add code snippet + relevant data instead of a picture. Also - Please show a complete data example - The picture does not show all values of list so how can we see that length is incorrect?

Comment: By the data example +picture you posted - it seems like the number of items is correct. For the selected row (third) - there are only 2 elements in list

Comment: But it should count each of them, for example, Unknown=1, email=2 etc and sum the total. So I do not understand why its not counting each element of the list as i thought it would

Comment: @GiladGreen I now get what you mean, yes it is correct. But I want to count each individual element. Is there a different way to utilize the len function to do so or do I need a new approach like a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I first placed the column into a string type and remove the '[]' with replace and then adjusted my function

```
def calc(path):
return len(path.split(','))
```